# Why my cartList is not updating in Java? When i print the list elements it gives me null value

Tags: java, phpmyadmin

[This is the full code, its up on GitHub](https://github.com/Raduci/JavaProject)

With this code I want to get from database the info about the products and put them into a list, then print the list.

In the  method named `addProductToCart(Scanner input)` I get the message "The return statement is never used". Also where i declare the list: `private static List<Product> cartList = new ArrayList<>();` I get the message "Field cartList might be final"

```
public class Main {

    private static List<Product> cartList = new ArrayList<>();

    private static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/storedb";
    private static final String USER = "root";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "";
    static Connection connection;
    static PreparedStatement pStatement;
    static Statement statement;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, SQLException {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int choice = input.nextInt();

switch(choice){
case 1 -> addProductToCart(input);
case 2 - > displayProductsFromCart();}

private static List<Product> addProductToCart(Scanner input) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the item you want to add to your cart");
         connection = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL, USER, PASSWORD);
         String sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE Name = ? AND ((AlcoholPercentage > 0 AND Kcal = 0) OR (AlcoholPercentage = 0 AND Kcal > 0))";
         input.nextLine();
         String productName = input.next();

         pStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
         pStatement.setString(1, productName);

        ResultSet resultSet = pStatement.executeQuery();

         while(resultSet.next()){
             int id = resultSet.getInt("ID");
             productName = resultSet.getString("Name");
             double price = resultSet.getDouble("Price");
             int quantity = resultSet.getInt("Quantity");
             double alcoholpercentage = resultSet.getDouble("AlcoholPercentage");
             int kcal = resultSet.getInt("Kcal");

             if(alcoholpercentage != 0){
                 cartList.add(new AlcoholicBeverage(id, productName, price, quantity, alcoholpercentage));
             }else{
                 cartList.add(new FoodProduct(id, productName, price, quantity, kcal));
             }

             System.out.println("You addeed to your cart: " + productName + " product!");
         }
         return cartList;
    }

    private static void displayProductsFromCart(){
        for (Product product : cartList){
            System.out.println(product.getName() + " - $" + product.getPrice());
        }
    }

}

}
```

[image: This is how the console looks like]

[image: This is how the database table products looks like]

Comment: You are returning a variable that is already in the class scope. Declare a variable inside the addProductToCart method and return it. A different approach is to not return it and just use a void method. The latter is not the best option in this case.

Comment: If I use the variable inside the addProductToCart ( the variable is a List) and i return it I can't call the displayProductsFromCart method because the variableis only in the first method, and wouldn't work it out, I already tried this ( maybe I did it the wrong way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is updating. This code has.. many bugs.

### `static` confusion

Your `addProductToCart` method doesn't create a list, it uses the `static` field `cartList`. This is a bad idea; static is best avoided until much, much later. `main` has to be `static`, but get out immediately:

```
public class ShoppingCart {
  private List<Product> cart = new ArrayList<Product>();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ShoppingCart().go();
  }

  void go() {
  }
}
```

is a much better setup.

Your `addProductToCart` method returns this list, but this is mostly pointless - code can *already* access it via `Main.cartList` and that is in fact exactly what you do in `displayProductsFromCart`. Your two bugs more or less cancel out; nevertheless, your linting tool (a tool that checks your code for dubious things, style mistakes, and likely errors) catches one of the two.

Given that `cart` is a field, your `addProductToCart` method should be declared to return `void`.

### You ARE printing it

Your `displayProductsFromCart` method works fine - after all, it prints 1 line per item in the cart and *it prints a line*. It's just that the product you are printing has, as name, `null`, and as value, nothing.

Looking at your github repo, your `AlcoholicBeverage` class is broken. It has a constructor that takes in an int, a String, a double, and so on - but this constructor **does nothing**. You have to actually assign these local variables to the fields (method params turn into local variables - and like all local variables, once a method ends, these local variables poof out of existence entirely - and a constructor is just a special kind of method).

That constructor should contain `this.price = price;` and so on. Or, replace it with `record` (a new feature that, presumably, whatever book you are following doesn't know about yet; they cannot extend another class in any case so isn't going to work with this type hierarchy setup).

Given that your constructor does nothing, the fields return their initial values, which is `null` for name and `0.0` for price, and that is exactly what your display method prints.

Comment: Not `private List<Product> cart = new ArrayList<>();`?

Comment: That's nitpicking rather a lot, don't you think?

Comment: Your code is Java 6. I don't think it's nit picking to mention something that's 17 years behind the times.

Comment: It works just fine on java17. Diamond is not mandatory.

Comment: As expected because Java promises that all code that ever compiled in any version will forever compile in future releases. Never mind...